# I can't change font weight or font size

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm a beginner web developer so this will probably be a rookie question. I wanted to use different fonts for the site I'm currently designing. But, no matter what value I give to the font-weight or font-size property, nothing changes. Yes, I embedded the fonts in the  section. I'll include the code. Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
  font-weight: 700
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Sacramento", cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather:wght@400;700&family=Montserrat&family=Sacramento&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  test text
  <h1>h1 test</h1>
  <h2>h2 test</h2>
  <h3>h3 test</h3>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no text content. At least from the code you shared. Do you have anything inside the `<body>` tag in the HTML file?

Comment: Yes, I have text content inside them.

Comment: @Utku Orçan: your css should work flawlessly. However, your actual site might also include overriding rules (e.g if you're using a framewoirk like bootstrap). Check your chrome/firefox devtools for errors. E.g Is your custom css actually loaded? (you would see a 404 error log otherwise)

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet that runs here on stack overflow, and your code works fine. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to reproduce the issue on here and with the least code possible. Follow @herrstrietzel's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all fonts supports all font-weight values 
For example, Sacramento font that you use for `h1` tag, 
as I see on google fonts page, 
only supports Regular 400 font-weight

font-size should work as usual for all fonts, 
try `font-size: 100px;` for example

Comment: I'm aware of Sacramento but the font I'm trying to change is Merriweather, and it has a bold 700 font-weight for example. I tried both values of 700 and bold, but they don't make any changes.

Comment: The Merriweather font you have only two options for font-weight, 400 and 700, as I see in your import google font.
Font-weight bold and 700 are the same